# What is the meaning of this sentence and why did the Giant rip open his belly?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The giant struck several heavy blows on the bed which Jack slept with his club but he had laid a billet in the bed in his stead before that.

> With that, greatly wondering, the giant led Jack to breakfast,
>   bringing him a bowl containing four gallons of hasty pudding. Being
>   loth to let the giant think it too much for him, Jack put a large
>   leather bag under his loose coat, in such a way that he could convey
>   the pudding into it without its being perceived. Then, telling the
>   giant he would show him a trick, taking a knife, Jack ripped open the
>   bag, and out came all the hasty pudding. Whereupon, saying, **'Odds**
>   **splutters her nails, hur can do that trick hurself'**, the monster took
>   the knife, and ripping open his belly, fell down dead.

This is from English fairly tales. I can't understand the meaning " Odds splutters her nails, hur can do that trick hurself ". What is the word "hur" and why did the Giant rip open his belly? Could you teach me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Giant's speech is the author's jocular way of depicting the Giant as a dimwit who speaks markedly sub-standard English. (Note that he is said to be a Welsh giant.)

"Odds splutters her nails" is a meaningless exclamation which has the form of certain archaic [minced oaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath)—"Odds bodkins", for instance, which is a euphemistic way of saying "By God's body".

"Hur can do that trick hurself" uses the third-person objective pronoun *her* for both subjective and objective forms of the first-person pronoun *I/me*—the Giant means "I can do that trick myself".

The Giant thinks Jack has ripped open his own belly and allowed his guts to spill out, without suffering any harm; to demonstrate that he is just as clever as Jack, he performs the same trick on himself.